# How to design database, one table for all product type or each table for each product type?

Tags: database, database-design

I start new e-commerce web application (pet project) that sale both t-shirt and shoe. My store has only free size T shirt so t-shirt has only color column while shoe has columns for size and color.

Now it's time to create table to store that data, I want to know is it good to create separate table for shoe and t-shirt or it's better to keep all of them in one table?

If it has a better idea to store such data, please let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You definitely don't want to create a Shoe table and a TShirt table. Your shop might grow, and one day you'll have a thousand such product tables. Writing SQL for that would be a nightmare. Plus, you might have different kinds of t-shirts eventually, some with color, some with size and color, and so on. If you create a new table for each, you'll lose track of them quickly, and if you don't, why have separate tables for t-shirts and shoes, but not for one-size t-shirts and multi-size t-shirts?

While designing your database, you should be asking yourself: what are the entities in my realm? what are the things that never change and are uniquely identifiable? In a shop, a particular item that can be sold at a particular price is one such entity. So you might have a products table that has a key for each particular item you sell, and maybe a name, a type, a size and a color column:

```
 item
 id | type | name     | size  | color
 ------------------------------------
 1  | shoe | Marathon | 9     | white
 2  | shoe | Marathon | 9     | black
```

Looking at this table, you notice that we have two entries for the highly successful Marathon running shoe, and that seems to be a normalization violation. Indeed, you probably have two entities a shippable item and a catalog product. The shoe "Marathon" is probably something that has one picture and one description in your store, followed by a "available in the following colors and sizes:" line. So now you have two tables:

```
product
id | type   | name        | supplier        | picture      | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | shoe   | Marathon    | TrackNField Co. | marathon.jpg | Run faster than light!
2  | tshirt | FlowerPower | SF Shirts       | fpower.jpg   | If you're going to San Francisco...


item
id | product_id | size | color | price
--------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 9    | white | 99.99
2  | 1          | 9    | black | 99.99
3  | 2          |      | blue  | 19.99
```

The "type" column in the product table can be a tricky one. You'll probably want to display products by category, let the user click on "shoes" and get all products with type "shoe". Easy so far, but eventually someone will mistype an entry "sheo", and then you can't find that product under shoes anymore. So it's better to separate the categorization from the products, for example by having a product_type table:

```
product_type
id | name
---------
1  | shoe


product
id | type_id   | name        | supplier        | picture      | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1         | Marathon    | TrackNField Co. | marathon.jpg | Run faster than light!
```

with a reference to the type in the product table. That's ok as long as your type hierarchy stays shallow, but what if you want to have subcategories, like "sneaker", "basketball shoe", "suede shoe", and so on? One shoe might even belong to several of these subcategories. In that case you can try this

```
category
id | name         | supercategory_id
------------------------------------  
1  | shoe         |
2  | running shoe | 1


product_category
product_id | category_id
------------------------
1          | 2


product
id | name        | supplier        | picture      | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Marathon    | TrackNField Co. | marathon.jpg | Run faster than light!
```

And if you want to display multiple hierarchies of categorizations (as most big ecommerce sites do these days), you'll have to come up with something even more sophisticated.

Answer (score 4):

Keep them all in one table and have a `type` field.  The reason to do it this way is so that your data structure is scalable: i.e. if there is a new type of product then instead of adding a new table and having to drastically change your application code, you just use the same table and simply add a `type`.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want make it to complex you can keep all of them in the same table and create another table called "ProductType" that tells you if it is a shoe or a t-shirt.
The relationship will be One-To-Many on the "ProductType" side as you can  have the same type of product associated with more then one record on the product table(where you store all your products)